# Is setTimeout() a higher order function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, higher-order-functions

A higher order function is a function which takes one or more functions as arguments and/or returns a function as a result. I have read on various sources online that `setTimeout()` is a HOF but ChatGPT states that `setTimeout()` is not a HOF. Can someone clarify?

So `setTimeout(functionRef, delay)` also takes a function as an argument hence it should be a higher order function. But ChatGPT states that it is not a HOF!

Comment: If it accepts a function as a parameter then by definition, it is a higher-order function. Maybe the fact that the function is a callback (to be called at a later time) it does not count. Seems like ChatGPT is erring on the side of it being a grey-area in that regard.

Comment: I think chatGPT is just wrong

Comment: ChatGPT is wrong *most* of the time. It's a next word predictor designed to generate confident, plausible sounding text; not a research tool.

Comment: yes, setTimeout is a Higher-Order Function. It takes another function as an argument and calls that particular function after a defined amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function),

> A function that returns a function or takes other functions as
> arguments is called a higher-order function

*setTimeout* definitely
takes a function ref (A function to be executed after the timer expires) as a parameter, so it is a higher order function.